# Custom color scheme in sublime3 for python - class names

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I've created a custom color scheme for sublime text 3 for python. Unfortunately I can't get a working foreground for class names.

```
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Class name</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>entity.name.class</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#CD950C</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Why is this tagged with Sublime Text 3?

Comment: Because i'm an idiot. I've edited the post and changed eclipse to sublime

Comment: I see, I was going to say that I didn't know Eclipse changed its theme format to Sublime's...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one tiny mistake - the name of the scope. It's actually `entity.name.type.class.python`, but you can omit the `.python` if you wish.

If you're interested in theming, there are two plugins I highly recommend. The first, for serious hard-core color scheme designers like me, is [`ScopeAlways`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ScopeAlways). It does just what its name says - displays the current scope at the cursor point (or the first cursor, if you have multiple) in the bottom status bar. You can turn it off if you want, as it can get a bit annoying. The second, less intrusive plugin is [`ScopeHunter`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ScopeHunter), which is triggered by a custom key combination or by selection from the Command Palette. It is quite configurable, and can display the current scope info in a popup window or quick panel, and has the added feature that you can copy the entire scope string if you wish, instead of trying to correctly type it all in by hand.

Good luck!